# How to remove automatically inserted Queries from Propel(Symfony)?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel

I'm writing some Database queries with Propel(symfony), but propel always add some query!
For example :

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE (table.start>='2012-06-01 00:00:00' 
AND table.end<='2012-06-30 00:00:00') AND table.deleteat IS NOT NULL
```

The Propel always add the : **AND table.deleteat IS NULL**

Can i remove that?

Comment: Show us your schema.xml / yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the Idea @j0k

In my schema.yml i saw that there exist a soft_delete. For the next Query just disable it with : `BookQuery::disableSoftDelete();`  [link](http://www.propelorm.org/behaviors/soft-delete.html)

Comment: It wasn't really an idea, we just need some code to help you ;-)